# GCP Terraform cloud_router module --how can I reference the self_link of a single subnetwork in my nat configuration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform, nat, vpc

I have been struggling with this for hours and can't make it work.
I am using external modules in my main.tf to deploy a GCP VPC with a public and private subnet, and I want to configure NAT for one of the subnets (the private one).

My VPC is configured like this:

```
module "vpc" {
    source = "github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-network"
    project_id   = var.project_id
    network_name = var.network_name
    routing_mode = "REGIONAL"

    subnets = [
        {
            subnet_name           = var.pub_subnet
            subnet_ip             = var.pub_cidr
            subnet_region         = var.region
        },
        {
            subnet_name           = var.priv_subnet
            subnet_ip             = var.priv_cidr
            subnet_region         = var.region
            subnet_private_access = true
            subnet_flow_logs      = true
        },
    ]
    routes = [
        {
            name                   = "egress-internet"
            description            = "route through IGW to access internet"
            destination_range      = "0.0.0.0/0"
            tags                   = "egress-inet"
            next_hop_internet      = "true"
        },
    ]
}
```

Ater the VPC module block, I have a "cloud_router" block that is meant to configure NAT for the private subnet, but I cannot get the "name" value correct. From the docs I read, this is looking for the self_link of the subnetwork.  How can I get this working?

```
    module "cloud_router" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/cloud-router/google"
  version = "~> 0.4"

  name    = var.cloud_router
  project = var.project_id
  region  = var.region
  network = module.vpc.network_self_link
  nats = [{
      name = var.cloud_nat
      source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
      subnetwork = {
          name = "${module.vpc.subnets_self_links[0]}"
          // <self_link>
          // {{API base url}}/projects/{{your project}}/{{location type}}/{{location}}/{{resource type}}/{{name}}
          source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
      }
  }]
}
```

Comment: " can't make it work" is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: sorry, should have posted the error msg: module.cloud_router.google_compute_router_nat.nats["liproj-ops-management-nat"]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating RouterNat: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.nats[0].subnetworks': ''. Must provide some subnetworks if Nat is configured with option LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS., invalid

Comment: I have since updated the "cloud_router" configuration to this:

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by moving the nat configuration into a 'resource' definition instead of nesting it inside the 'cloud_router' module:

```
resource "google_compute_router_nat" "nat_manual" {
  name   = var.cloud_nat
  router = module.cloud_router.router.name
  region = module.cloud_router.router.region

  nat_ip_allocate_option = "AUTO_ONLY"
  //nat_ips                = google_compute_address.address.*.self_link

  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"
  subnetwork {
    name                    = "${module.vpc.subnets_self_links[0]}"
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
  }
}
```